# Trying to sort two list of numbers and using uniq to get the intersection

Tags: sort, uniq

I have a file A and B so I used to the following command...

```
(sort -n A B) | uniq -d
```

which should give me the numbers which occur in both files.

```
1
2
2
3
4
5
11
11
12
31
```

These are the numbers I get from `sort -n A B` but when I pipe it to `uniq -d` I only get 11 and not 2. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Assuming the files are sorted, `join A B` is another option to acquire the intersection.

Comment: @don_crissti Thanks but I checked that already no trailing spaces. I even sent the output to a txt file still no trailing spaces....

Comment: @don_crissti So what do I do to check or to avoid this? I manually checked the file there is nothing but you are right there is something. When I add a two consecutive 2's elsewhere it works.

Comment: Can either input file contain duplicates within itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments indicate, the problem seems likely to be blanks or carriage returns.  Either of the following should do the trick:

```
$ (sort -n A B) | sed -E 's/[^[:alnum:]]+$//' | uniq -d
$ (sort -n A B) | tr -d '\r ' | uniq -d
```

Some flavors of GNU sed use `-r` instead to get Extended Regular Expressions.   `tr` is certainly simpler but also more brutal in that it removes the characters whether or not they're trailing.

Comment: +1. With GNU sed, `sed 's/\r$//'` will strip trailing carriage-returns too.

Answer (score 3):

Because it's not used as much, I'll mention a [comm](/questions/tagged/comm)-based solution:

```
comm -12 <(sort A) <(sort B)
```

This uses process substitution `<( ... )` to sort files A and B and provide them as inputs to `comm`, which then uses `-12` to:

> ```
>   -1     suppress column 1 (lines unique to FILE1) 
>   -2     suppress column 2 (lines unique to FILE2)
> ```

... leaving only lines common to both files.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what don_crissti mentions about trailing spaces you may want to check the filetype / newline style as well.  The man page for uniq states that it can:

```
uniq - report or omit repeated lines
```

If you have say CRLF i.e. Windows style newline characters instead of the expected LF, you might get surprises.

You can quickly check the type with:

```
file <filename>
```

If you want to remove any CRLF endline sequences you can run the input files through dos2unix.  The following will convert the end line characters.

```
dos2unix A
dos2unix B
```

Comment: It seems like you're on the right track. Filetype A and B are both CRLF and when I redirect them into a txt after running sort -n A B the filetype of that one is CRLF, LF. So what should I do in this case?

Comment: I would just run the A and B files through the `dos2unix` command and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the file size you could just use `grep`:

```
grep -Fxf A B
```

`-f` specifies a file from which to get a list of patterns.

`-x` means to match the whole line only (disallow matching a part of a line).

`-F` means to treat the patterns as fixed strings rather than regular expressions.

If `B` is smaller than `A` you may get slightly faster results by naming `B` as the pattern file (`grep -Fxf B A`).

You can pipe the output to `sort -u` to get a sorted list of the distinct lines that occur in each file:

```
grep -Fxf A B | sort -u
```

---

Of course if your problem is carriage return line endings, you should use `dos2unix` first.